# checkbox value to = true

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to get the value of "Data" to equal true when checkbox is clicked and false when it isn't, so when it is used in the query string it is either true or false, can anyone help please?

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="getItems">    
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:500;height:180px">
    <apex:form onsubmit="openWindowPopup(); return false;" styleClass="formId">
        <apex:pageblock id="table">
            <script>
            var openWindowPopup = function(){
                var Data = document.getElementsByClassName("DataId")[0].value
                window.open('https://www.local.com?messages-data='+Data);
                }
            </script>
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!AssetLines}" var="lines">   
                    <apex:column headerValue="Data">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!lines.Data__c}" styleClass="DataId"/> 
                    </apex:column>                                            
            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("DataId")[0].checked
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but it works thanks :)